# Send transaction error

Tags: error

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@solana/web3.js@v1.33.0/lib/index.iife.js"></script>
    <title>Vision Pro (VSN)</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="header__container">
            <h1>VISION PRO</h1>
            <ul>
                <li><button id="connect_button" onclick="connectWallet()">Connect wallet</button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
    <img class="first__background" src="images/background.png" alt="">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="block main">
            <div class="container__block">
                <img height="100px" style="border-radius: 50px;" src="images/photo_2024-02-10_23-38-08.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="about">
                    <h2>Vision Pro</h2>
                    <p>$VSN</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="progress_bar">
                <h3>Total raise</h3>
                <h3>Progress: 100.00%</h3>
                <h3>HardCap: 1500 $SOL</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="line__progress_bar">
                <div class="progress"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="socials">
                <p id="walletMessage" class="connect">Connect wallet to deposit</p>
                <div id="socials">
                <input type="number" id="quantity" step="0.1" min="0.1" max="50" placeholder="Enter amount (SOL)">
                <button id="depositButton" onclick="sendButtonClick()">Deposit</button>
                <p id="status_p"><span id="status"></span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("socials").style.display = "none";
        
        
        var wallet;
        const lamports_per_sol = solanaWeb3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL;
        async function connectWallet() {
    if (window.solana) {
        try {
            wallet = await window.solana.connect();
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        window.solana.on(
            "connect",
            () => (
                document.getElementById("connect_button").innerText = "Connected",
                document.getElementById("walletMessage").style.display = "none",
                document.getElementById("socials").style.display = "block"
            )
        );
    } else if (window.Trust) {
        try {
            wallet = new Trust.Web3Provider();
            await wallet.enable();
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        
    } else {
        console.log("No wallet provider detected.");
    }
}

    
        async function sendButtonClick() {
          const receiverAddress = "5AZbfDTE4ZrdBpyZrWdzB5u8VeZQyRiKVBXzmcKCKUzJ"
    
          const quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value
          if (quantity != null && quantity != 0) {
            document.getElementById("status_p").text = "Status";
            document.getElementById("status_p").innerText = "Sending " + quantity + " SOL to " + ellipsizeAddress(receiverAddress) + " account address";
            await signInTransactionAndSendMoney(receiverAddress, quantity)
          } else {
            document.getElementById("status_p").text = "Status";
            document.getElementById("status_p").innerText = "Amount must be more than 0!"
          }
    
        }
    
        function ellipsizeAddress(str) {
          if (str.length > 35) {
            return str.substr(0, 8) + '...' + str.substr(str.length - 8, str.length);
          }
          return str;
        }
    
        function signInTransactionAndSendMoney(destPubkeyStr, quantity) {
          (async () => {
            const network = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com";
            const connection = new solanaWeb3.Connection(network);
            const transaction = new solanaWeb3.Transaction();
    
            try {
              const lamports = quantity * lamports_per_sol;
    
              console.log("starting sendMoney");
              const destPubkey = new solanaWeb3.PublicKey(destPubkeyStr);
              const walletAccountInfo = await connection.getAccountInfo(
                wallet.publicKey
              );
              console.log("wallet data size", walletAccountInfo?.data.length);
    
              const receiverAccountInfo = await connection.getAccountInfo(
                destPubkey
              );
              console.log("receiver data size", receiverAccountInfo?.data.length);
    
              const instruction = solanaWeb3.SystemProgram.transfer({
                fromPubkey: wallet.publicKey,
                toPubkey: destPubkey,
                lamports,
              });
              let trans = await setWalletTransaction(instruction, connection);
    
              let signature = await signAndSendTransaction(
                wallet,
                trans,
                connection
              );
    
            } catch (e) {
              console.warn("Failed", e);
            }
    
          })();
    
          async function setWalletTransaction(instruction, connection) {
            const transaction = new solanaWeb3.Transaction();
            transaction.add(instruction);
            transaction.feePayer = wallet.publicKey;
            let hash = await connection.getRecentBlockhash();
            console.log("blockhash", hash);
            transaction.recentBlockhash = hash.blockhash;
            return transaction;
          }
    
          async function signAndSendTransaction(wallet, transaction, connection) {
            const { signature } = await window.solana.signAndSendTransaction(
              transaction
            );
            await connection.confirmTransaction(signature);
            return signature;
          }
        }

        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When i click Deposit, i have error in console

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
index.html:140  Failed Error: failed to get info about account HPFpsvyxaY2fzYxXsp7L3vQi5J4hKbhMSoryYrQHjqP7: Error: 403 :  {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code": 403, "message":"Access forbidden, contact your app developer or support@rpcpool.com."}, "id": "13eb9434-b783-47ca-ac34-adf5c5d4bc08" }

```
at Connection.getAccountInfo (connection.ts:2546:13)
at async index.html:116:41
```

How to fix this

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use a custom RPC in this case. Check out Alchemy, Helius or Quicknode, they all offer free RPCs which are perfectly suited for hobby level applications.